# Live Time in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

There is an app in Windows Store called "The Time" which shows current time (every minute) on its Tile. The app can do this without registering any Background Task.

How can it do this?

**UPDATE:** it seems that it schedules lots and lots of tiles!
Because if you draw back the computer time, it will stop working.
However, I don't know how many tiles it schedules and how many tiles it is possible to schedule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the author himself:

1. Live tile updates may be scheduled
2. Applications may be given slices of time via the background task infrastructure

So, simply, when The Time’s background tasks are executed by the OS they queue up a number of live tile updates.

Comment: Using Windows 8 on my laptop, I have noticed that this app updates time right after I switch to the 'Start' page. Any idea, which event it has registered with? Is it UserPresent event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemconditiontype.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible in Windows 8 - the background task for updating tiles can run every 15 minutes, but not more frequently.
[Being productive in the background – background tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx)